# OpenShift Nodes Fail To Start

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift, openshift-origin

I am trying to install OpenShift 3.10 on two VMs. The VMs have passed the prerequisite checks, but once it comes to starting the web console, the installer fails because the web console wasn't able to be reached.

Using the `oc get nodes` command, I checked to see if the nodes became available, but there was an error for the "Ready" state. The following is the error message that was displayed:
`runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized`

In addition to the nodes not starting, the pods also failed to start, probably for the same reason.

How can I fix this problem so that the nodes become available? Any help would be appreciated :D

Answer (score 0):

This could be a misconfiguration in any step, but I might be wrong. Can you check if:

1. You've configured the correct `openshift_node_labels` in your inventory file.
2. You're installing using the correct version of Ansible(the one in the `requirements.txt` of the [openshift-ansible](https://github.com/openshift/openshift-ansible) repository).

Comment: I fixed the nodes not getting ready by using a different SDN plugin (Calico). However, now my pods fail to start "NetworkPlugin cni failed to set up pod"... Any tips on what I can check here?